# MFC C++, adding seconds (int) to a current CTime variable

Tags: c++, mfc, ctime

noob to C++.
I have a `CTime` (actually it's a `CTimeEx`) object. The value of the time value is:

```
CExTime now = now.GetSystemTime();
```

I am receiving an `int`, such as 60, to add to that time; this means that if I have 12:01:30 , then I'd want 12:02:30.

How can I add the `int` to the `CTime`? Would this work?

```
currBERecored.m_BeUpdateTime = now + secondsFromFile;
```

Comment: What are `CTimeEx` and `CExTime`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add via the `+` operator a [CTimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/ctimespan-class?view=msvc-160#ctimespan) to a `CTime` object. The `CTimeSpan` is the correct class to represent a time interval, you can construct a CTimeSpan of a certain number of seconds by using this constructor:

```
CTimeSpan(
   __time64_t time 
) throw( );
```

in which time is the desired amount of seconds.